# How to quote in HTML (not blockquote)?

Tags: html, quotes

I want to some sample code in a html page. How do I do it, for example I want to show a tag and image tag, in stackoverflow I use 4 spaces:

```
A Tag example:
<a href="your_url"></a>

Image Tag example:
<img...>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're asking for the `<pre>` tag for preformatted text.

Everything that goes inside the pre tag it's not interpreted.

Try this on a browser:

```
<pre>
&lt;img src="whatever" /&gt;
&lt;othertag&gt;whatever&lt;/otherta&gt;
</pre>
```

EDIT: As Pekka pointed out, for HTML tags, symbols must be converted to their HTML entities.

Comment: Not in my browser - I still get an interpreted image. Are you sure this is correct? IIRC, you need to make HTML entities out of the control characters in any case, `pre` or not.

Comment: You're right, symbols must be converted to their respective HTML entities, sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 6):

To format the output, you can use the [**pre**](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_pre.asp) element.

Howver, you will still need to turn the special characters `<` `>` `'` `"` `&` into their HTML entities `&lt;` `&gt;` and so on so the HTML tags turn up in clear text and don't get rendered by the browser.

If you can use **PHP**, there is [**htmlspecialchars()**](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) for that. Every server-side scripting language has an equivalent of it.

In **JavaScript**, setting the `innerText` property of the `pre` container leads to the characters being displayed literally and not as interpreted HTML.

If you want to do it manually, this is what you need to convert:

```
& to &amp;
> to &gt;
< to &lt;
" to &quot;
' to &#039
```

[**source**](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of the [`<pre>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) and [`<code>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_phrase_elements.asp) tags.  The `<pre>` tag formats everything inside of it as is appears in the source code (useful for showing large blocks of source), and the `<code>` tag is used for inline formatting of code (similar to how the tags in this answer are formatted).  Also, anything inside the `<code>` tags need to be converted into HTML special characters (& gt; and & lt; for example).