# output code AS IS

Tags: php, html, escaping

**add in note**
i have to paste 3 time the following code in the html body of a static webpage, instead of having to paste it and have a lot of code, i prefer to only have one line (3 times) that call the writing of the code, like this : `<?php getgooglepub(); ?>`

---

I like to make a php function that will ouput to the hmtl page the google analitic code or adsense.... hot to format the code to output "as is" with all the<>""''

here is the sample code to output :

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "pub-0743213818925076";
/* 728x90, date de création 11/02/10 */
google_ad_slot = "9774402576";
google_ad_width = 870;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

---

Note, despite the creative answer, i found myselft now beeing able to make it work... for sure, my fautl.... i will copy-paste the code, for sure, you will flag the problem, since i have no clue !..

```
function getgooglepub()
{$google_code = <<<EOT

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "pub-0743213818925076";
/* 728x90, date de création 11/02/10 */
google_ad_slot = "9774402576";
google_ad_width = 870;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>

EOT;

echo htmlspecialchars($google_code);}
```

after that in the html code there is the call

```
<?php getgooglepub(); ?>
```

---

This is the source code from the page render in firefox... abviousely not working

```
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;&lt;!--
google_ad_client = &quot;pub-0743213818925076&quot;;
/* 728x90, date de création 11/02/10 */
google_ad_slot = &quot;9774402576&quot;;
google_ad_width = 870;
google_ad_height = 90;
//--&gt;
&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;
src=&quot;http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js&quot;&gt;

&lt;/script&gt;
```

---

i have read somewhere about the [data] tag ?.... it maybe a way to do that ?

Comment: If you want to display the html as-is, then that's what the page source _should_ look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the answer is right, and do print code "as is" it does not do it the way i want. Maybe i dont have explain it the right way. So i have found a solution. I use a external php file with the code, and after that in the main file i use the include. that way i only have one code that i can reuse many time, thanks anyway !

Answer (score 4):

If you want to output some HTML code *(and see the actual HTML code without having it interpreted)*, you can use a combinaison of both :

- `<pre>` tags, so the presentation of the orinal code is kept ; i.e. linebreaks and multiple-spaces are not ignored by the browser
- and a function such as [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars), so `<`, `>`, `&` and quotes are escaped -- so they aree not interpreted by the browser.

For instance :

```
$str = <<<HTML
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "pub-0743213818925076";
/* 728x90, date de création 11/02/10 */
google_ad_slot = "9774402576";
google_ad_width = 870;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
HTML;

echo '<pre>';
echo htmlspecialchars($str);
echo '</pre>';
die;
```

Shoud display the HTML code, without it being interpreted by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your HTML code in a variable, use

```
echo htmlspecialchars($google_analytics);
```

See [**this question from yesterday**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245465/how-to-quote-in-html-not-blockquote/2245492#2245492) for a detailed explanation.

if it's not in a variable yet, you can use HEREDOC notation for convenience:

```
$google_analytics = <<<EOT

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "pub-0743213818925076";
/* 728x90, date de création 11/02/10 */
google_ad_slot = "9774402576";
google_ad_width = 870;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>


EOT;

echo htmlspecialchars($google_analytics);
```