# BlockQuote Tag Only Produces One Line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add code to my website with block-quotes, but it seems like I'm the only one having this problem. I simply put:

```
blah
{
    blghta
}
```

But it comes out on the site:
blah{blghta}

How can I add inputs and newlines without manually going through each line and adding a break and whatever is used for indents?

Edit: Even on this website, it turns out bad. Is it something with my browser? I have Windows XP and Google Chrome(latest version).

http://gyazo.com/e9e00996819a2bfb018582e65352a85a.png

Comment: sure looks like it. I can see it spread into 3 lines. I even checked the edit logs to see if someone changed it

Comment: Hm. Could you possibly suggest a fix? I'll try the <pre> tag, Torr3nt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `<pre>` tag instead. That should show up correctly. Also, an easy one to google.

[How to quote in HTML (not blockquote)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245465/how-to-quote-in-html-not-blockquote)

Edit: My bad. You don't have to use the `<pre>` tag, just emulate it. Try:

```
blockquote {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: It works well, but is there not an easy way for the BlockQuote to work? I would prefer it because of it's better UI on my site, but I can work without it.

Comment: I would suggest `pre-wrap`, not `pre`. That way longer lines of text are automatically wrapped, *and* white-space is preserved.